# Set write permissions on ProgramData subfolder using JNA

Tags: java, windows, jna

I have a program, written in Java, which originally used its directory in Program Files to write files accessible to all users of this program. This required our users to run as administrator all the time. In an effort to alleviate that, we decided to move files which needed to be written during regular usage to the `ProgramData` folder using the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` environment variable. Using a subfolder in this directory for our application works great if it is designated as writable during the installation process, which works fine using NSIS.

The problem comes with upgrading existing users. The Java File API provides `setWritable` but this does not appear to work after testing on development machines. It looks as though the new file API with Java 7 would solve this problem, but with no release date on the horizon I would rather not wait.

It seems the simplest solution would be to use JNA to call the appropriate Windows API call to set this directory writable. Since upgrading the software necessitates admin rights, similar to installing, it should let this change go through fine. However, I'm unsure where to start, having never used JNA before or the Windows API. Suggestions as to which Windows library to load and what functions to call would be appreciated, especially if someone has encountered a similar problem before.

Comment: IMHO too broad question. Try to read some more on JNA / WinAPI functions you may need and narrow the question.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why not just use `cacls`?

Comment: @Dmitri: As a primarily Java guy, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm glad you gave some background...You could use JNA, but the easier way would be to execute a call to the command-line utility cacls. It's included by default in Windows XP installations, I believe, so it should do the trick for you. Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cacls.exe"+options)`

Check out the documentation here -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx

Comment: On my system at least, the appropriate group to work with is BUILTIN\Users. Do you know off the top of your head if that's a constant value that'll always work, or if it's system/version dependent, subject to internationalization, etc?

Comment: Have you tried using the "Application Data" directory? If you used that,you wouldn't need to change the permissions to write to that folder. The downside is that if the files you're writing need to be accessible to the end-users through the file system, they won't be able to see it because it's a hidden folder. But if the data is only meant to be used by the program,then it's perfect for sharing data across users.`> cacls "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data"` [...] `BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)R BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(special access:) FILE_WRITE_DATA FILE_APPEND_DATA FILE_WRITE_EA FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES`

Comment: And, to more directly answer your question, I believe that BUILTIN\Users and the other builtins exist on every machine. If you're asking if that's the permission that you need to change to access it, that should do the trick, yes. And by default, on this machine, BUILTIN\Users has read access to that dir. `> cacls "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%"` [...] `BUILTIN\Users:R` But you're still probably better off with the "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data" directory, if it suits your needs as described above.

Comment: Since it's all internal bookkeeping data that end users can't/shouldn't muck with, the fact that it's hidden by default is a plus. And yeah, my original comment wasn't as clear as I meant -- BUILTIN\Users is the group I modified to grant full access to my application's folder in `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\App` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I use the follow line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "C:\\Windows\\System32\\icacls.exe \"%ProgramData%\my application" /grant *S-1-5-32-545:(OI)(CI)(W,M)" );
```

S-1-5-32-545 is the SID for BUILTIN\Users because the name work only on English systems. https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/163846

This give the BUILTIN\Users write access to all files in the given directory independent which user has create it.